# React Javascript wait until then finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await

It does not wait to display When I get data from AsyncStorage

It returns value before catches the value.

I cannot use Async Await on functions. If so it does not compile.

I have searched around the whole day today but I could not find the answer.

How can I solve this simple problem, but complex to me?

React code

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, AsyncStorage, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getUsername } from '../actions';


export default HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    DisplayUsername = () => {
        var info = useSelector(state => state.login_info_reducer);
        if (Object.entries(info).length === 0 && info.constructor === Object) {
            AsyncStorage.getItem('username').then(name => {
                info.username = name;

                return info;
            });
        }
        else {
            return info;
        }
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Friends') }}>
                <Text>Welcome {DisplayUsername()}</Text>
                <Text>Click Here</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer -- I'm familiar with the web version of React but I'm guessing that these patterns are similar if not identical in react-native.)

You're trying to do something asynchronous (`DisplayUsername`) during a synchronous operation (`render`). React does not permit render to be asynchronous; your render function always needs to return something that React understands (either UI elements or an empty value such as `null` or an empty array).

That means your component has two states: one state where it doesn't yet know what the username is, and one state where it has finished using `AsyncStorage`, and it does know the user name. That's a hint that you can use react `state` to hold the user name data.

The 'standard' way to fetch external data in React is to do it in a component's `componentDidUpdate` method (which is fired after the component has first rendered) or the `useEffect` hook with functional components (which is fired after every render). So this is what you want to implement:

1. component renders the first time, without the username. maybe it shows a loader element?
2. component fetches user's username from `AsyncStorage`, asynchronously
3. when result is received, update component state
4. a state change always triggers a re-render, so now you can render with the username

Here's some psuedocode for implementing those steps with a functional component:

```
export default HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    // set up state and setter for username state
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    // effect hook for fetching username
    useEffect(() => {
      doSomethingToGetUsername().then(result => {
        setUsername(result);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }, [username]);

    const usernameTxt = ` ${username}` || '';

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Friends') }}>
                <Text>Welcome{usernameTxt}</Text>
                <Text>Click Here</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```